Convolution theorem for Laplace-Beltrami eigenfunctions?
Eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator are the generalisation of harmonic functions to arbitrary manifolds. You can show that the eigenfunctions are linearly independent and dense on $L^2(M)$.
Is there also a generalisation of the convolution theorem, $FT\{f*g\} = FT\{f\}FT\{g\}$, where FT denotes the Fourier transform?
Edit:
Particularly the case where one of the functions is zonal and we can define convolution as $(f*g)(x) = \int_M g(d(x,y))f(y)d\mu(y)$.
I know there is a result like this for spherical harmonics and I'm wondering if it's generalisable.

How do you define convolution on a smooth manifold? This necessarily requires some sort of group structure and it may not be the case that this group plays nicely with the LB operator as it does in the case of the real line

@whpowell96 Ah I see, do you know of generalisations for the cases when we can define a convolution. In particular, I care about the case where one of the functions is zonal and we can define convolution as $(f*g)(x) = \int_M g(d(x,y))f(y)d\mu(y)$. I know there is a result like this for spherical harmonics but I'm wondering if it's generalisable.

How does this work? $g$ is defined on the manifold but you are evaluating $g$ at a real number in the integral

Well, it's like if you have a radially symmetric function defined in polar coordinates, you can write it as a function of r.

Yes but that presupposes the existence of some notion of axisymmetry on a smooth manifold. This notions needs to be specified and tightened
